# Adding Rows to View with Left Join (new to SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, view, sql-server-express

Background / Disclaimer: I have developed database applications in MS Access for several years so I already know the basics of database design etc. but have only been working with SQL server for about 3 months.

I am in the process of re-building a database that was initially built in MS Access to SQL server (but it will retain the MS-Access Front-End), the purpose of this is to track inventory of recyclable packaging that we return to our vendors.

I want a view that would allow our warehouse to quickly take a look at all the inventory we currently have on hand, select some quantity of each item and run a transaction that would remove that inventory from our system (As well as print a packing list but I know how I will handle that)

Right now I have a table of items that we can simplify to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
  ( ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ProductName nvarchar(64),
    < Other Details Multiple Fields >,
    InvQty int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "df_InvQty" DEFAULT (0) 
  )
```

I wanted to Create a view that joined this table with the current user's selected shipment quantity so i made another table to store the current user's Pending Shipments

```
CREATE TABLE PendingShipments
  ( UserName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT "df_UserName" DEFAULT (Suser_Sname()),
    ProductID int NOT NULL,
    SelectedQty int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "pk_PendingShipments" PRIMARY KEY (UserName,ProductID)
    CONSTRAINT "fk_ProductID" FOREIGN KEY ("ProductID") REFERENCES "Products" ("ID")
  )
```

Next I created a view 
    SELECT P.ID, P.ProductName, P.InvQty, S.SelectedQty
      FROM Products AS P LEFT JOIN PendingShipments AS S ON P.ID = S.ProductID
      WHERE S.UserName = Suser_Sname();

I know that if I were to do this exact same thing in MS Access I would automatically create a new record in the table PendingShipments if I were to fill in a value in SelectedQuantity. but when attempting htis in SSMS I get the error

'Data has changed since the Results pane was last retrieved. Do you want to save your changes now? (Optimistic Concurrency Control Error)'

but I am the only person in this database, are there ghosts changing the data? When I click 'Yes' to commit the changes I get the error

'No row was updated. The updated row has been changed or deleted since data was last retrieved.'

can anyone please help me out? If what I am trying to do here is inherently stupid I am open to major design changes as I am still very early in development and am willling to burn everythign down and start over.

Comment: In Sql Server, AFAIK you can only insert / update through a view if a single base table is affected. Perhaps look at a Proc to do the functionality required?

Comment: You need to either insert directly into the base tables, or use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view to parse the inserts to the correct tables.